# Why is components constructor called multiple times while it has to be reused by router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm reading [this article](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-router-state-7b5b95a12eab#.4lcmwutv2) where the author states the following:

> To avoid unnecessary DOM modifications, the router will reuse the
>   components when the parameters of the corresponding routes change.

And he continues with the example where `MessageCmp` is reused. As I understand, it's not destroyed and re-created, hence the observables are used to track chanages:

```
class MessageCmp {
  message: Observable<Message>;
  constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.message = r.data.map(d => d.message);
  }
}
```

I have the following route configuration:

```
path: 'tasks',
component: ExTasksComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ExTaskListComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ExTaskViewComponent,
```

So I was expecting that `ExTaskViewComponent` will be reused when navigating from `/tasks/3` to `/tasks/4`. However, the constructor of the component is executed each time the navigation occurs? Am I missing something?

I'm navigating using `routerLink` directives.

Comment: My guess is it unloads it because the 'tasks' route has it's own component ref. So when it walks the route tree, it unloads the ExTaskViewComponent, because it first encounters the ExTaskComponent on the tasks root route (;-)). Try removing that component on the 'tasks' path

Comment: @MikeOne, thanks, I've figured out the problem. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42418990/2545680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had the following navigation steps:

```
/tasks/3
/tasks
/tasks/2
```

And hence the component got destroyed when navigating to `/tasks`. I was under impression that the router state is preserved for some time and not destroyed immediately when navigating out of the current route.